# html span tag in iphone webview

Tags: iphone, html

how can i break the line in sapn tag. when line is big. I have used following code for that in iphone as webview.

Website Url:
                    %@

but when website url is longer so the screen no look like proper with alignment. so how can i manage the alignment in that case.

please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<br/>` tag but span is a inline element which means if you use `<br/>` it'll b considered as one line anyway.

Change span to a block element or add display:block to your class to solve the problem.